# What bootstrap @media-query is active right now?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

While we are developing or debugging a responsive design, might be very useful see an indicator to show which @media-query is applied. i.e (xs, sm, md or lg).

I wondered, How can i show in a simple way which @media-query is active in bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I played around this snippet that uses `visible-[xs|sm|md|lg]` classes.

Additionally I added the following extra CSS that also allow you see an indicator for landscape and portrait media queries.

#### Extra styles required by the Landscape and Portrait indicator.

```css
.visible-landscape, 
.visible-portrait {
   display: block;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
    .visible-landscape {
       display: none !important;
    }
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
    .visible-portrait {
         display: none !important;         
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style='position:fixed; z-index: 10001; top:0; left: 0; background: black; color: white;'>
  <span class="visible-xs">XS</span>
  <span class="visible-sm">SM</span>
  <span class="visible-md">MD</span>
  <span class="visible-lg">LG</span>
  <span class='visible-portrait' style="background: red; color: yellow;">OP</span>
  <span class='visible-landscape' style="background: red; color: yellow;">OL</span>
</div>
```